# hide extension with htaccess is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

My hosting is from namecheap and I use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I get 404 error when I try to access a php file without extension.
I know it was discussed many times but the solutions here from stackoverflow are not working for me.

Comment: Try using an absolute target path `/$1.php` instead of `$1.php` if this doesn't  work  then perhaps  `mod-rewrite` isn't enabled on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

**Note**: Above solution is for Apache version 2.4 and above as END flag isn't supported by older versions.

Comment: Still the same error, I found this solution with multiviews as well but for godaddy anyways I tried too and same error.

Comment: @John what is version of apache you are using?

Comment: I have no ideea I tried to find out but seems they don't allow you to see the version it outputs only "Apache".

Comment: @John `phpinfo();` can display apache version. I have update my answer again please try it again

Comment: wait a second because I already contacted the support from namecheap and is already working they modified something I will message you soon I know what they did.

Comment: Your rule will return a 500 internal server if used on Apache version less then 2.4 as END flag isn't supported by older versions.

Comment: @Hassaan they said it was something wrong into my code there for redirect non www to www and they fixed by writting a individual rule for my domain name, I was using the {HTTP_HOST} and now I see they commented that line and added an individual one for my domain name.

Comment: @John you did not mentioned that you have redirect code in your question :)
I think you should share your answer to resolve problem for further poeple

Comment: @Hassaan I tried without my old code too and same problem, then when I contacted them I uploaded the old code and I don't know but now is working.

Comment: @Hassaan your code is now working + my old code, I have no ideea why now is working. I think they maybe did some changes in apache ?!

Comment: @starkeen thank you. I have added note in my answer :)